# VS2010 color change

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, colors, color-scheme

Every time I put a cursor on a variable in VS2010 it highlights it and any other place where its used with gray background. I know that in Fonts and Colors we can change color schemes. Which Display Item is responsible for this please ? Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Display item is: "Highlighted Reference" (about 1/3 of the way down my list). :)

*With the  "Show settings for:" showing "Text Editor"*

See below screenshot.

Hope this helps.

[image: Options Screen with Highlighted Reference Selected]